# Using an IF ELSE statement to find user option & redirect appropriately

Tags: php, html

Very inexperienced with EE 2.4, but im experienced with PHP & HTML. I am attempting to use the following code to get variables from URL & then run an IF/IF ELSE statement:

```
<?php $firstname=$_GET[“firstname”]; $zipcode=$_GET[“zipcode”]; $option=$_GET[“option”];
  if ($option==”Instant Medigap Prices”) { header(‘Location: 1’); } 
  elseif ($option==”2”) { header(‘Location: location2test’); } 
  elseif ($option==”3”){ header(‘Location: location3test’); } 
  elseif ($option==”4”){ header(“Location: location4test”); }
?>
```

Obviously the above wont work in EE with php enabled. How can i change it to allow it to work within EE 2.4? I’ve also tried using Mo Variables for aid but still unsure on implementation. i.e. how do i set a var

{get:option}

Help & Clarification much appreciated !!

Comment: Developer docs: https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/development/usage/input.html#fetching-a-superglobal-value

Answer (score 1):

Not positive the following will work on 2.4, but try it:

With a url `mysite.com/news/latest?option=abcd` and Mo Variables you should be able to get query string variables within an if/else conditional like:

```
{if "{get:option}" == "abcd"} 
    {redirect="TEMPLATE_GROUP/TEMPLATE"}
{if:elseif "{get:option}" == "1"}
    {redirect="TEMPLATE_GROUP/TEMPLATE"}
{if:elseif "{get:option}" == "2"}
    {redirect="TEMPLATE_GROUP/TEMPLATE"}
{/if}
```

and then [redirect](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v2/templates/globals/single_variables.html#redirect). Change the TEMPLATE_GROUP/TEMPLATE text to the template group and template you're wanting to route to (i.e.: news/index).

In mo variables "Add GET: {get:your_key}" needs to be enabled in settings (Add-Ons > Extensions > Mo' Variables > Settings).

*Also, note ee 2.4 is pretty old at this point and many changes have been made in subsequent 2.x updates.*